# Change disclosure indicator color on cell selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I've read some posts on this, but still can't get the answer to my question.

I have a disclosure indicator. [image]

I add it like this:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Everything works fine and is good, the only thing i want to change is when i press down the cell, disclosure indicator changes color to white. [image] I don't want that. So my question is how to make the disclosure indicator color fixed, and not changing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a custom accessory view for this.
Syntax:

```
cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory.png"]] autorelease];
```

Here you are assigning an **image view** with an image **accessory.png**

to your cell's accessory view.

Comment: but is there no other way? I don't want to make my own custom view, because i have multiple tables in my app, so this would be quite a lot of work, i'm looking for some easier way :)

Comment: no, it's the default behaviour of UITableViewCells, if you want to override that, you need to add your own custom accessory view.

Comment: done like that, hoped for a better way, but well, it works.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

Add a custom accessory view:

*Example 1:*

```
cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "accessory.png"))
```

*Example 2:*

Nested in an view container for a small source image:

```
let accessoryView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 50))
let accessoryViewImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "accessory.png"))
accessoryViewImage.center = CGPoint(x: 12, y: 25)
accessoryView.addSubview(accessoryViewImage)

cell.accessoryView = accessoryView
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. Probably you'll be able to achieve what you want.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        for (id obj in cell.subviews){
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                UIButton *button = obj;
                for(id btnObj in button.subviews){
                    if([btnObj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                        UIImageView *imgView = btnObj;
                        UIImage *image = [imgView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
                        imgView.image = image;
                        imgView.tintColor = cell.backgroundColor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with uiimageview to apply cell accessoryType like below code:

```
cell.accessoryView = myAccessoryUIImageView;
```

cell accessoryview uiimageview not align correctly try below code:

```
    UIView* accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 50)];
    UIImageView* accessoryViewImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory_image.png"]];
    accessoryViewImage.center = CGPointMake(12, 25);
    [accessoryView addSubview:accessoryViewImage];
    [cell setAccessoryView:accessoryView];
    [accessoryViewImage release];//not use this line your ios sdk in 5.0 and above! 
    [accessoryView release];//not use this line your ios sdk in 5.0 and above!
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and found even you're struggling with this...though its quite late answer but I sorted out my issue by writing the following line,

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

it stopped accessory type UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator from being white when selected.

Hope this helped.

---

Swift version:

`cell.selectionStyle = .none`

Comment: This should be a correct/shortest answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** - a simple Table View class that can show a disclosure indicator or not using the `showsDisclosure` boolean when configuring the cell. right now the disclosure arrow tint color is hard coded, but your color choice could easily be passed in through the configure function as well if you wanted a more reusable cell.

Note that the 'chevron' image is set to be a template image in the asset catalog, which means that it can be tinted a color. You can alternatively make a UIImage into a template image in code like so: `UIImage(named: "chevron")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`

```
class HeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var sectionTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        sectionTitle.textColor = .black
    }

    func configure(title: String, showsDisclosure: Bool = false) {
        self.sectionTitle.text = title

        if showDisclosure {
            //add custom disclosure arrow
            let chevronImgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "chevron"))
            chevronImgView.tintColor = .red
            self.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            self.accessoryView = chevronImgView
        } else {
            self.accessoryType = .none
            self.accessoryView = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[[UITableViewCell appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: The image on the disclosure indicator isn't set to AlwaysTemplate, so this doesn't work.